# is it possible to scan a pd document and find certain symbols or objects

Tags: java, c, pdf, ocr, scanning

I have multiple pdf documents (600+) and I would like to search for certain objects or symbols like a circle (they are all the same size). Once I find them I would like the x/y coordinate of the circle, the center or any point of the circle.

If anyone has any ideas as to whether this can even be achieved please let me know.

Thank you.

Joe.

Comment: Are those many PDFs generated alike (and especially are the symbols you search always generated alike)? Or are they from different sources? In the former case you can search the content streams of the documents for the drawing sequences those PDFs use for creating  those symbols. In the latter case I would propose rendering the PDFs to bitmaps and using algorithms for searching given images (your symbols) in bitmaps.

Comment: It looks like you are looking for an app or trying to create one. PDF is a software with a user interface not a developer interface. You need to find out, if PDF has an open source PDF library or a distributed binary code that you can use to manipulate the PDF user interface to get what you are trying to do. Otherwise this sounds like building a PDF app, which in most cases is very likely.

Comment: All the pdf's are generated alike. The "circle" i am trying to detect is identical in size in every page. I am not limited to PDF, since I can convert the file into different formats i.e .ai files or png for example. I just want to determine the coordinates. Any more thoughts would be greatly appreciated.